# JPDL: How does "join" with "multiplicity" work?

Tags: java, join, workflow, jbpm, jpdl

On https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v4/devguide/html_single/, the chapter *2.3. Multiplicative split with foreach* contains an example with `join` attributed with `multiplicity`.

The comment under the example says only:

> When using foreach, the corresponding join must have the multiplicity attribute set. Without it, join continues execution based on its incoming transitions. In the preceding example, join has a single incoming transition. If multiplicity is not specified, the first execution that reaches the join activity will cause the parent execution to leave the join.

What is the role of the attribute `multiplicity`? Especially, what happens if its value (`#{quorum}` in the example) is lesser or greater than the number of tasks?